# on-line recording with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Is this possible? Someone tried to do on-line recording of audio and video(of the screen) with ffmpeg? I read everything google can find about ffmpeg in the net. The variant of recording I deed load CPU to 100%, but it still can't convert frames with appr. speed relevant to how fast frames are recording, audio go good, but video lost frames..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording audio/video of the screen is possible with ffmpeg. People do this for the purposes of screen casting. Performance of this depends on the hardware in use, the codecs used and various other factors.

See [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583257) (or [this one](http://verb3k.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-do-proper-screencasts-on-linux/)) for some further advice and command line use.

Comment: thanks, begin to read.. but the thing is that I'm using ffmpeg libs in my c++-application, I'm not just using ffmpeg with it cmd

Comment: @Alecs if it's possible with the command line it can be done from the libs

Comment: yes, but since all normal documentation of ffmpeg is about cmd, and about libs is almost absent at all, it's very hard to look into code and understand what functions I need for this or that :(

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg.org/developer.html - `libavcodec is the library containing the codecs (both encoding and decoding). Look at `libavcodec/apiexample.c' to see how to use it. libavformat is the library containing the file format handling (mux and demux code for several formats). Look at `ffplay.c' to use it in a player. See `libavformat/output-example.c' to use it to generate audio or video streams. `

Comment: I've already. I have no problems if I want to open, convert file, I can create a new file. The problem is with on-line screencastion to a normal file(I mean avi or something else that can be played with most players), CPU's converting speed is much smaller that recording speed

Comment: @Alecs: if you're not bound to a codec, library and platform, you can try directly using the X264 library for video encoding. I used it for such a purpose and found it far superior to the ffmpeg libs. Of course you'll also need another audio solution (x264 and ffmpeg licenses are incompatible).

Comment: @KillianDS and what did you use for audio? And you mean this libs - http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html ?

Comment: Honestly, that was a research project that was focusing on video, I'm planning to expand it with audio and probably will try the vorbis codec first but I cannot give you any experience yet.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much depends on the codec used, the frame size/complexity and obviously the capabilities of the computer doing the compression. You can try a low complexity codec like MJPEG, which might improve your experience.